# btrfs-transacti kills my VMWare guests, because it makes I/O unresponsive

Tags: vmware, btrfs

Most of the time when BTRFS maintenance starts with process btrfs-transacti, my VMWare guest cannot access disk and restarts. Is there anything I can do? I tried to give to guest machine high io priority with ionice, but that does not help.

Answer (score 0):

OK, no one answers, so my answer can come handy. The CPU usage of btrfs-transactio (and the cleaner process) can be limited with tool cpulimit. It sits in background and if btrfs-transacti takes too much cpu, it will throttle it. That should theoretically give more space to I/O processes of vmware guests.